# Best approach to using for loops to reorder columns in a list of dataframes?

Tags: r, list, dplyr, purrr

I've got a list of dataframes, and I am trying to change the order of the columns.  I have the exact error message when I run this example using mtcars:

```
cyl.4 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl==4) %>% select(mpg,carb,gear)
cyl.5 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl==5) %>% select(mpg,carb,gear)

x <- list(cyl.4,cyl.5)

for (i in seq_along(x)){
  names(x[[i]]) <- x[c(2,1,3)]
}
```

I'm new to R and programming, so please forgive this novice question.  I've been struggling for a while, and I'd like to use other for loops to do similar data cleaning. I can't find a previously asked question on reordering columns in lists of dataframes.  I've also tried to use the purrr package, but it's a bit too advanced for me. Thanks

Comment: Since you tagged this with `purrr`, you could use `map()` and `select()`: `map(x, ~select(.x, c(2,1,3)))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your current code, `x[c(2,1,3)]` is a data.frame: you don't want to use that to provide columns names. Also, you don't want to use `names()<-` that would only rename columns but  reorder them.

You can try:

```
cyl.4 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl==4) %>% select(mpg,carb,gear)
cyl.5 <- mtcars %>% filter(cyl==5) %>% select(mpg,carb,gear)

x <- list(cyl.4,cyl.5)

for (i in seq_along(x)){
  x[[i]] <- x[[i]][c(2,1,3)]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily without a loop:

```
x <- lapply(x, `[`, , c(2, 1, 3))

x
[[1]]
   carb  mpg gear
1     1 22.8    4
2     2 24.4    4
3     2 22.8    4
4     1 32.4    4
5     2 30.4    4
6     1 33.9    4
7     1 21.5    3
8     1 27.3    4
9     2 26.0    5
10    2 30.4    5
11    2 21.4    4

[[2]]
[1] carb mpg  gear
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: That's a good approach, it also uses a (lapply-) loop though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit confused on what the `[`, , c(2, 1, 3) does.  Why have '[' , , ?

Comment: The `\`[\`` is the function used to select elements from dataframes (as in `df[2,3]`). For a dataframe it takes two arguments - in this case the first one is blank (because we want all rows), and the second is the columns. So we are going through each element `df` of the list and returning `df[,c(2,1,3)]` (which can also be written `\`[\`(df,,c(2,1,3))`)